# How do I run a for loop so it generates repeated samples of n observations?

Tags: r

I first generated random data from a Gamma distribution using the following code

```
data <- rgamma(9, shape=32, scale=1/4)
```

I proceeded to generate a single sample of 9 observations from the population.

```
sample(data, 9)
```

I'm trying to run a for loop in R so that I can repeatedly generate samples of 9 observations and save the mean of each sample into a new vector. I want to do this 500,000 times. After the for loop I then want to create a null distribution based on the distribution created from the for loop. I am also wanting to sample with replacement. (I am also very new to R, so any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated).

Here is the code I have tried for the for loop:

```
v <- 500000
Storage <- numeric(9)

for (i in v) {
  Storage[i] <- mean(i)
}
```

Comment: Where are your samples coming from? What object hold your observations? Are you sampling with or without replacement?

Comment: Have a look at the `sample` function, which might make this job easier.

Comment: You've noticed that your code does not work. But you do not need to, *and should not!*, use a loop here. Your stated problem can be solved with a single function call: `storage <- mean(v)`.

Comment: I don't understand why you are sampling in this case. Your `data` seems to only contain 9 values. If you take a sample of 9 values from 9 values, you just get those same values (if you are sampling without replacements). It's not clear to me what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replicate` to create the vectors, then compute the means with the fast `colMeans`.

```r
set.seed(2023)
data <- rgamma(9, shape=32, scale=1/4)

v <- 500000L

Storage <- replicate(v, sample(data, 9, TRUE))

mean_Storage <- colMeans(Storage)
hist(mean_Storage, freq = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Or maybe you want to sample from a Gamma distribution.

```r
set.seed(2023)

v <- 500000L

Storage <- replicate(v, rgamma(9, shape=32, scale=1/4))

mean_Storage <- colMeans(Storage)
hist(mean_Storage, freq = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is like this...

```
means <- replicate(500000, mean(rgamma(9, shape=32, scale=1/4)))
```

This will generate 9 gamma variates, take the mean, and repeat the process 500,000 times, storing the result in the vector `means`. Definitely no need for a for loop!

Comment: Excellent answer.  Note that according to the Central Limit Theorem the means of your samples are Normally distributed with mean = mean of your original distribution and sd = sd original distribution / sqrt(sample size).  Very important general concept.